# How to access vertex_color layer directly from inside BMVert

Tags: python, scripting, vertex-colors, bmesh

I want to access vertex colors directly from inside BMVerts, but I don't know how.
I am able to access vertex colors indirect for inside BMFaces:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
layer_color = bm.loops.layers.color.get("col_test")
for bmf in bm.faces:
    #bmf.loops[0][layer_color] = new_color
    for loop in bmf.loops:
        color = loop[layer_color]
        print(color)
        loop[layer_color] = new_color
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
```

But this way I loop multiple times through the same vertex colors, because a face vertex is owned by multiple faces.
I don't want to loop through all faces only to get access to the vertex colors.

I am looking for something more direct, like:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
layer_color = bm.loops.layers.color.get("col_test")
for bmv in bm.verts:
    color = bmv.????[layer_color]
    print(color)
    bmv.????[layer_color] = new_color
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
```

It seems there is no "interface" to access the vertex color from insider a BMVert directly, or am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex colors are stored in face loops, you can't ignore/overlook this.

However its reasonable that you might want to generate vertex colors per vertex and not have to deal with looping on vertex-loops while generating/manipulating the colors.

Your best options would be to have 2 functions for converting colors between loops and verts. This could take & return array of `Color` objects. Then at least you can keep the conversion isolated and not complicate your color calculation logic. *(If your generating new colors you only need one function to go from vertices to loops of course)*

Comment: my fault was, i overlooked / did not realize, that i can assign each **face-vertex** an other vertex-color. in vertex-paint-mode that behavior is not/hard to see.
so it is like, at the coordinates of one vertex, each face that is using that same vertex can have different vertex-colors.
i thought that the vertex-color is stored to a vertex, so that each face, that is using the same vertex would get the same color at that coordinate.

Comment: Hmmm, looping thru all polys and then looping thru all their loops really doesn't scale well... So there's really no way around it? I could write vertex color to an obj and import it, but I kinda like the concept of face-vertex, as it sorta gives smooth colors.